# convert horizontal table with multiple values to an aggregated vertical table

Tags: php, mysql

Im stuggling to think of how to do this, my brain is stumped.
First of all this is mysql and php.

I have a table with say 8 columns

```
id - user -a1 -a2 -a3 -a4 -a5 -a6
518   96   0   1   2   1   0   0
519  108   0   0   1   1   2   1
520   56   1   0   1   0   1   2

0 = no
1 = yes
2 = n/a
```

I want to be able to select say 6 of those columns, but i want to display like this:

```
Question - Yes                     - No      - N/A
   a1       %of all rows with 1     %of 0    %of 2
   a2       %of all rows with 1     %of 0    %of 2
   a3       %of all rows with 1     %of 0    %of 2
   a4       %of all rows with 1     %of 0    %of 2 
   a5       %of all rows with 1     %of 0    %of 2
   a6       %of all rows with 1     %of 0    %of 2
```

For the % i presume i would just do something like this:

```
$i = 0;
if ($thequestion->a1==1) $i ++;
$num_amount = $i;
$num_total = '25';

$yespercentage = round($num_amount * 100 / $num_total)."%";
```

Any help/pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If i get this right you're trying to show a total percentage of "users" per value (0,1,2) right? Why couldnt you count each and group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this for a single question with `GROUP BY` and [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). You could then use UNION to combine 6 queries (for the six questions) to a single result. By using `SUM(CASE WHEN ...)` you can separately count the three cases: yes, no, n/a.

it's a bit long, but i don't know better than this. It should output exactly the table you need, without percentages. Feel free to insert calculation of percentages, which can also be done in this SQL:

```
SELECT 
  "a1" AS question,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS na,
  COUNT(id) AS total
FROM tbl 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  "a2" AS question,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS na,
  COUNT(id) AS total
FROM tbl 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  "a3" AS question,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a3 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a3 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS na,
  COUNT(id) AS total
FROM tbl 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  "a4" AS question,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a4 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a4 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS na,
  COUNT(id) AS total
FROM tbl 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  "a5" AS question,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a5 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a5 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a5 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS na,
  COUNT(id) AS total
FROM tbl 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  "a6" AS question,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a6 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS no,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a6 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS yes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a6 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS na,
  COUNT(id) AS total
FROM tbl
```

example percentage:

```
SELECT
  "a1" AS question,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(id) * 100) AS no_percentage,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(id) * 100) AS yes_percentage,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(id) * 100) AS na_percentage
FROM tbl
```

desired PHP print example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Question</td>
      <td>Yes %</td>
      <td>No %</td>
      <td>N/A %</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
// given this functions returns the result set as multi-dimensional array
$rows = get_records_sql($thequery);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->yes_percentage.'%</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->yes_percentage.'% </td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->no_percentage.'% </td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->na_percentage.'% </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was posting, beat me to it.. You'll get back percentage and everything's handled on the sql side of things.

Comment: thankyou for the response, ill give it a go and let you know how i get on.

Comment: @Kaii: Hi Sorry, just checked the example SQL percentage and it works great. How do i print this in php in a table formatted like the one in my question? $questions = get_records_sql("

SELECT
  'a1' AS question,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(id) * 100) AS no_percentage,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(id) * 100) AS yes_percentage,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(id) * 100) AS na_percentage
FROM mdl_iqer_checklist
");

Comment: @MatthewBrennand added php code to edited answer. would you mind accepting the answer, now after i invested so much work for you?

Comment: @Kaii: thanks for the quick response. I thought this was the Php as it is what i tried, but it is not working. If i run the SQL in phpmyadmin it returns the result, I then tried print_r on $thequery and i get the array but the php is not echoing.

Comment: Modified the answer with my final script whcih is working. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a1-NO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a1-Yes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a1 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a1-N/A,
       ...// similarly for all other columns
FROM table_name
```